# How to use formatstyle() to change color base off condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, dt

```
print(data)

Metric   2016   2017    2018      2019  Change Since 2016  
Average  110    104      95        96        -.146          
Median   41     44       42        47         .128
```

This is my code, theres some java script in there that formats a trendline in a different column that I didn't list in my data. And after running this it ouputs my data as such

```
DTdata <- datatable(data, rownames = FALSE,escape = FALSE, filter = 'none', 
                          options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                                         searching = FALSE,
                                         paging = FALSE,
                                         info = FALSE,
                                         fnDrawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                           '
function(){
  HTMLWidgets.staticRender();
}
'
                                         )
                          )) %>%
  spk_add_deps() %>%
  formatPercentage('Change Since 2016', digits = 1) %>% 
  formatStyle('Metric', fontWeight = 'bold') %>%
  formatStyle('Change Since 2016', fontWeight = 'bold') 



 DTdata
```

[image]

My goal is have some sort of logic to change the color of my values in the column 'Change Since 2016' to highlight huge changes.

So if the Change Since 2016 is decreasing by more 10% I would want it to be green(positive), and if increasing by more than 10% I would want it to be red (negative). If its between -10 & 10 I would want it to stay black.

Would I have to use a case when?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See section 2 https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Comment: So I see the command of how to change color, But I would still need to create a logical condition.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm actually not sure if it's possible to condition formatting on something other than what's shown in that specific cell. May need to file an issue on Rstudio's GH repo for `DT`.

Comment: Yea I read the DT manaual off CRAN and it looks like its not possible. But I was able to find a solution, its not as automatic as I wish it could be, but I essential did;  formatStyle('Change Since 2016', 'Metric',
              color = styleEqual(c("Average", "Median"), c('green', 'red')  and I got my desired output.

Comment: Please answer your own question to help future readers.